# how do you do lookup the name of some thing without knowing it

Tags: c++

I would like to know how to lookup something in C++. But I don't know the name of the object that I want. I know the path, and I know what I am looking for, but I don't have an actual pointer or reference to the actual object.

basically something I can put into:

```
if (ioctl(card_fd, signature, &path) != E_OK) return E_FAILED;
if (FindDirectory("/dev/graphics/*", 0, signature, &path) != E_OK)
   continue;
strcat(path, "/dev/graphics/*");
strcat(path, signature);  
if (name(path, &dev_name) != 0) continue;
dev_name = load_device(path);
if (card_fd < 0) return false;
```

---

Although I don't know if the above is correct

Comment: What kind of a thing is your thing? Furniture? Collectibles? The word "thing" is not useful. In general, to find something you don't know whatchamacallit, you ask the Google oracle on Mountain View. Google knows that stuff.

Comment: I guess you are trying to get a plug n play device name?

Comment: yeah. the signature is a bit iffy because I don't know if the device actually has one, but after that I want to try to grab it by the name.